# How to read elements of a column one after another to check if they match a certain condition?

Tags: python, bash

-1.4221738
-1.4874885
-1.4994459
-1.5108121
-1.5219439
-1.5332919
-1.5452454
-1.5580290
4.7115221
4.6972045
4.6825012 
4.6677902

Let's say, I have a data file like the one before. How can I read the elements of the column one after another and compare them to each other to match a certain condition? For example, if I want to keep the same value going on (-1.5580290) after 8th row when the numbers suddenly jump, how can I set that up in bash or python?

I was trying to save the numbers in an array and trying to iterate through them in bash. But, I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a can I haz codes?-question](https://can-i-haz.codes/) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). After that, edit your question accordingly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say your full data file's path is PATH. And every number is written in a line alone.

```
file = open(PATH, "r")
list = []
max_jump = 0.2
for line in file:
    list.append(float(line)) 
for i in range(1, length(list)):
    if abs(list[i - 1] - list[i]) > max_jump:
        list[i] = list[i - 1]
    else:
        continue
```

You can modify max_jump as you need.

Comment: Thanks. But, I actually wanted to know the next steps which is how can I compare one number to another while reading them on-the-fly. I will post the code I was trying to write in the answer section. Let me know if you have any more idea.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by comparing?

Comment: For example, if you see the numbers I have provided, there is a jump after the 8th element. The first 8 elements were all negative and then suddenly it changed to 4.71. What I want to do is for the code is to recognize that and make the last few rows same value as the 8th row. I reckon I have to read the numbers on-the-fly and set up a condition for the i-th and (i-1)-th element. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't try this, since it is 12:05 am in Lebanon . Tell me if it throws an error. I will help you after 10 hours at maximum.

Comment: Thanks. Take it easy. I will check it and let you know. :)

Comment: I took your code and made some changes according to what I wanted. I also needed to write them to another file which I did. Thank you! I wasted a lot of time trying to do it in bash before (I am not used to python that much). :P

Answer (score 0):

Using bash script, I am able to figure out if every number follows a certain condition, for example, positive or negative, where I have saved the numbers in an ARRAY.

`arraylength=${#ARRAY[@]}
for (( i=1; i<${arraylength}+1; i++ ))
do
       st=`echo "${ARRAY[$i-1]} < 0.0" | bc
       `if [ $st -eq 1 ]; then
               recog=negative
               echo "$recog" " " ${ARRAY[$i-1]}
       else
               recog=positive
               echo $recog " " ${ARRAY[$i-1]}
       fi
done`

However, I need to be able to compare the i-th value and the (i-1)-th/(i+1)-th value in the ARRAY depending on a condition and that code seems to not work properly. Any help in how to do it in shell or python would be appreciated.